# RTCmulticonnection getViewers + onjoin event

Tags: javascript, webrtc

I'm trying to get the amount of currently viewer of a stream.

I tried to trigger some codes whenever `onUserStatusChanged` is fired (used as if user onjoin event).

Something like:

```
connection.onUserStatusChanged = function(status) {
    console.log("onUserStatusChanged");
    updateViewers();
};

function updateViewers(){
    connection.getAllParticipants().forEach(function(participantId) {
        var peer = connection.peers[participantId];
        if(viewers && viewers.indexOf(peer.extra.nickname) === -1 && "UserA"  !== peer.extra.nickname)
            viewers.push(peer.extra.nickname);
    });
    console.log(viewers.length);
}
```

So far so good it works, But now it pushes also the user who has cam and not watching user A his cam.

I only want the `extra.nickname` of the user who is connected to User A his cam/channel/connection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Using "beforeAddingStream":

> Please download latest codes from github to use this "beforeAddingStream" method.

```
var listOfStreamReceivers = {};
connection.beforeAddingStream = function(stream, peer) {
    var remoteUserExtra = connection.peers[peer.userid].extra;
    listOfStreamReceivers[remoteUserExtra.nickname] = peer;
    return stream;
};
```

### Using "onExtraDataUpdated" and "updateExtraData"

```
var listOfStreamReceivers = {};

connection.onstream = function(event) {
    if (event.type == 'remote') {
        connection.extra.receivedStreamById = event.streamid;
        connection.updateExtraData();
    }
};

connection.onExtraDataUpdated = function(event) {
    if (event.extra.receivedStreamById) {
        listOfStreamReceivers[event.extra.nickname] = event;
    }
};
```

### Using data channels

```
connection.session.data = true;

var listOfStreamReceivers = {};

connection.onstream = function(event) {
    if (event.type == 'remote') {
        var data = {
            receivedStreamById: event.streamid
        };

        // second parameter sends direct message to the broadcast initiator
        connection.send(data, connection.sessionid);
    }
};

connection.onmessage = function(event) {
    if (event.data.receivedStreamById) {
        listOfStreamReceivers[event.extra.nickname] = event;
    }
};
```

### "listOfStreamReceivers" to array

```
var array = Object.keys(listOfStreamReceivers);

console.log('number of receivers', array.length);

array.forEach(function(key) {
    var peer = listOfStreamReceivers[key];

    var userid = peer.userid;
    var extra = peer.extra;
});
```

Comment: `connection.peers` returns

`Object
forEach
:
(callbcak)
getAllParticipants
:
(sender)
getLength
:
()
selectFirst
:
()
send
:
(data, remoteUserId)
__proto__
:
Object`
 can't get `connection.peers[peer.userid]`

Comment: Did you try "peer.extra" or otherwise use "setTimeout=>1000" to make sure "connection.peers" object has that userid. E.g. `setTimeout(function((var remoteUserId = connection.peers[peer.userid];) {}, 1000);`

Comment: Or otherwise use "userid" same as "nickname" e.g. `connection.userid='nickname'`; now you don't need to check for extra-data. You only needto check for `peer.userid` which will be a nickname.